# Java can't find the main class

Tags: java, cmd

My java can't find the main class `why.helloworld`.  and I can't figure out why. This is my code:

```
package why;
public class Helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("viva");
    }
}
```

Environment variables:

> CLASSPATH：.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
>   JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
>   Path :%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;

Comment: And what directory do you execute `java` from?

Comment: The command you use to run your program is: `java why.Helloworld` and not: `java Helloworld`, right?

Comment: What have you tried? Run `java why.HelloWorld`? If so, you have to check directories.
Using packages you have to create a directory `why` where to put the `HelloWorld.class`. Then run the command outside the directory `why`.

Comment: Please print your `Java` command also. You might not specifying package.

Comment: @AmitD He says it in the first sentence: *can't find the main class `why.helloworld'*. The package is right there. I hope he doesn't literally mean "helloworld", though.

Comment: sorry English is not my first language.I have to study both java and English

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That might also be problem `Helloworld` spelled wrong while typing the command.

Comment: Well, Winnie, if you really want help, then why don't you post the command line you are using to start your Java program?

Comment: sorry ,I 'm trying understanding your answers and comments

Comment: I saved the file in ' D:\project\src\why\Helloworld.java ' and javac ' why.java ',and java ' .Helloworld '

Comment: I find the mistake ,I javac the command in d: with d:,and lost 'why.'Thanks for all your help ,and is it because my question is too simple so I got downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have not sent your command line but I guess that you forgot to write the package name when running your application. Use command line:

`java -cp YOUR_CLASSPATH why.Helloworld`

run it from your project directory. The `YOUR_CLASSPATH` should be either `.` or name of your jar file or path to directory where your classes are. Probably it is `classes` or `bin` depending on your project structure.